# Manipulate/Edit a json encoded string value in a database row

Tags: php, json, string, laravel, laravel-4

I'm working with laravel 4 and the eloquent implementation.

I want to edit/manipulate a value in a database field which contains a json encoded string.

Example: I have a database row with the name "meta". The value of "meta" is a json encoded string.

The example json encoded string:

```
{"name":"steven","lastname":"builder"}
```

How can I manipulate the value of that json string?

For example "name" ?

I've found mutators but I dont know how to work with them.

http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#accessors-and-mutators

Comment: Considering that's just an ORM framework you're looking at, just pull out the value, decode it or modify however you want, re-encode, put it back in as an update statement.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm already decoding the meta row with an accessor. But how can I save a new value. Like the example above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works like most ORM's in that you simply make the change like you would to a normal object's properties, and just save the changes. In this example:

You've already got who you want to update, so we'll just call that object $meta, and you've already manipulated your json, so we'll call it $manip_json, and we'll say the column name is just meta_col

```
$meta->meta_col = $manip_json;
$meta->save();
```